# How to get only specific metrics from Google Lighthouse?

Tags: puppeteer, lighthouse

Let's suppose I'd only like to get the `first-meaningful-paint` [metric](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/audits/metrics/first-meaningful-paint.js) from [Google Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/tree/master).

I'm using the below snippet of code, which does a full audit (which takes too long, since I'm only interested in one metric). How can I change the below code to tell Lighthouse to only get one metric for me?

(Source code snippet based on [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/puppeteer.md#inject-jscss-before-the-page-loads))

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const urlLib = require('url').URL;

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null
    });

    const { lhr } = await lighthouse("https://www.google.com", {
        port: (new urlLib(browser.wsEndpoint())).port,
        logLevel: 'info',
        output: 'json'
    });

    console.log(lhr);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `settings` object of the configuration, you can specify which audits to run. When calling `lighthouse`, the configuration is provided as third argument (more information in the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/readme.md#configuration)).

**Code Sample**

```js
lighthouse('...', { /* ... */ }, {
  extends: 'lighthouse:default',
  settings: {
    onlyAudits: ['first-meaningful-paint'],
  }
});
```

This will only run the [`first-meaningful-paint`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/first-meaningful-paint) audit.

Comment: How can I display the audit -> network-request data in the report? Can you help me with the custom audit config settings?